# Accordion full width sections open on click UPDATE: smooth slideToggly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, accordion, sections

**Update:**

I building a responsive accordion function inside a website, but i have a problem with the animation of the slideToggle function, because it isn't working smoothly and i found out that it is caused by my header(logo in header not showed here), because when i remove it the animation is smooth, but i need the header. Maybe the problem lies in more areas like my main.js script, but i'm not sure. Beside this problem i would like a close all button function, but the first problem is more important so if someone could help me?

Here the example: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/foroloca/w3srayj6/13/)
.

Help would be must appreciated, thank you!

```
<header class="fadeIn" id="logo"></header>      

<div class="read-more">Scroll voor meer</div>

<section id="line"></section>

<section id="container">
    <div class="header"><h1>Het verhaal</h1></div>
    <div class="content"><p>Alles wat hier staat is slechts om een indruk te geven van het grafische effect van tekst op deze plek. Wat u hier leest is een voorbeeldtekst. Deze wordt later vervangen door de uiteindelijke tekst, die nu nog niet bekend is. De faketekst is dus een tekst die eigenlijk nergens over gaat.</p>
    <p>Het grappige is, dat mensen deze toch vaak lezen. Zelfs als men weet dat het om een faketekst gaat, lezen ze toch door. Kijk eens hoe een link <a href="#">test@google.nl</a> eruit ziet. </p></div>
</section>

<section id="line"></section>

<section id="container">
    <div class="header"><h1>DJ/bands</h1></div>
    <div class="content"><p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusan tium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore <a href="#">architecto</a> veritatis et quasi  beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit.</p>
    <p>Nulla viverra condimentum sem, a rhoncus lectus. Fusce pharetra non magna eu venenatis. Cras fringilla aliquam erat, vitae imperdiet nisl congue id. Ut pellentesque pellentesque lorem a aliquet. Ut imperdiet tortor in metus pretium, in aliquet nisl tempus.</p></div>
</section>
```

**Old problem *(this was the beginning of the thread)*:**

*(I building a website with full width sections and the text centered, but i want it to function as a accordion and open its content (slide down animation) under the title when clicked and only! when opened have a topcorner close button and stay open when others are opened. Also when opened not have the hover color any more on the text etc. In fiddle i have displayed the text-wrapper to 'none' as example)*

Comment: Does someone know a solution to this problem?

Comment: In the fiddle example that i made you can't really see that it does not run smoothly on my end. But i know it's because the header or maybe another jquery library etc.? It is frustrating...

Answer (score 0):

You can retreive clicked element then navigate to it's parent.

```
$(".header-wrapper").click(function(){
    $(".text-wrapper",$(this).parent()).slideToggle();
})
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/nh6dmr5q/

Comment: Not exactly a solution to your answer, but I guess you can figure out how to do the rest.

Comment: A appreciate your help any way! But animation isn't very smooth slide down and want it to open not when clicking on the header but the whole section and when open, show close button, color on hover gone etc. But i have something to go one, thanks.